# Compute generalized pentagram map

Tags: computational-geometry, reference-request, convex-polytopes, mg.metric-geometry

Hi,

(This is my first question on MathOverflow! :-)

Imagine you have a set of points $S = \{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, of which $t$ are "bad". I want to compute a "safe convex hull", which is defined by $$ \bigcap_{S' \subseteq S} \mathrm{Hull}(S') \mathrm{,}$$ where $S'$ is constructed from $S$ taking away $t$ points -- in other words, $|S'| = |S| - t$.

This convex hull is necessarily inside the convex hull of the good points only. That's the interpretation of the "safe convex hull".

For $n = 5$ and $t = 1$, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is the [Pentagram Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram_map); for any polytope and $t = 1$, this is the very central part of the interior of a [star polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon#Interiors_of_star_polygons).

Do you guys know any procedure that does that for arbitrary dimensions, and for $t > 1$? A reference would be fantastic.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: It is likely that for small t, the intersection will be empty.  For some reason the "guard number" (in a 2d polygonal art gallery, the number of guards
needed to see all the faces from inside) comes to mind, and is possibly relevant.  An interesting combinatorial twist: Consider a diagonal d inside a polygon.  Which d live in the greatest number of
convex hulls of vertices of the polygon?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.04

Comment: Is $d$ fixed? Naively, you can take every collection of $d$ points, check if there are at most $t$ points on one side, then intersect those $n^d$ half-spaces.

Comment: @Michael Biro: Yes, $d$ is fixed. The problem is that you can pick $d$ points that are not affine; in this case, how to divide the entire space? (thanks!)

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman: I can show, using the Helly's Theorem, that if $n >  t(d+1)$ this safe convex hull will always exist. (thanks too!)

Comment: @Michael Biro: Let me be more clear. Suppose all the $n$ points are in a single line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now, every 3 points I pick will be in a single line as well. So, the procedure would not detect that I could just remove the extremal $t$ points at both ends of the line to find the safe convex hull.

It seems that I need to perform likewise in every smaller dimension before doing so in dimension $d$, but I'm not sure. Since the problem seems elementary, I suppose I could find a reference somewhere (in a paper or even in a book).

Comment: You safe convex hull is the intersection of all half-spaces which contain $m=n-k$ points.

You need to check all hyperplanes which pass through $d+1$ points and have $k$ points on one side and take the intersection of opposite half-spaces.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: The problem is when the points are all in a single line segment, say. See the comment before yours. In that case, it is unclear how to chose a hyperplane (which should be across $d$ instead of $d+1$ processors, right?) - thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think that's a serious issue. Just find the convex hull first, and if the points are degenerate, move down to the proper dimension so that the half-space intersection idea works.

Comment: Does anyone know a reference (a book, or paper) where I can reference to this?